# Regular expression .*? failed to find the first matching character if there is a equal sign (=) before the matching character

Tags: regex, string

I'm just trying to get all the attributes from this xml tag using regular expression.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,somthing=" width="280" height="186" >
```

I'm currently using `[^ ]*[ ]*=[ ]*\".*?\"`, which is matching anything, then one or zero space, then an eqaul sign, then one or zero space, then double quote, and then find the next double quote.

The problem is that if there is an equal sign, the double quote get skipped 
[image]

If there is no equal sign in the end, everything works fine. Where did I miss?

[image]

Comment: Please don't spam a post with random tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using * operator when trying to capture one or zero spaces (`[ ]*`), the operator you want to use is this one instead **'?'** (`[ ]?`)

As a suggestion, here's how I would capture the atributes is the xml tag:

```
\w+\s?=\s?\".*?\"
```

**EDIT**:By the way, * Operator captures zero or more matches, not zero or one as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Given your exemple, the following regex seems more intuitive : (\S{5,})

The use of {5,} is just here to get rid of < img and >
See output : https://regex101.com/r/Nfj6zr/3

Comment: yeah my example works but if I have a space in any places, it won't work. But good to know that such a simple regex is partially working :)